# tkinter redraw a scrollable canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

From another StackOverflow, I've got this code example that shows how to dynamically size a canvas around a frame with widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
class Image(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry("400x150")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(False,False)


        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="sunken", padx=3, pady=3, bd=1)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") 
        

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
    
        menu = SideMenu(container, self)
        menu.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nwe")
        menu.configure(relief="ridge", padx= 3)

        self.frames = {}

        startpage = StartPage(container, self)
        backuppage = BackupPage(container, self)
        restorepage = RestorePage(container, self)
        progresspage = ProgressPage(container, self)


        self.frames[StartPage] = startpage
        self.frames[BackupPage] = backuppage
        self.frames[RestorePage] = restorepage
        self.frames[ProgressPage] = progresspage


        startpage.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        backuppage.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        restorepage.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        progresspage.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bd=1)
        startpage_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        startpage_lbl.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill="both")
        
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Image")

class BackupPage(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text="Backup", bd=1)

    
class RestorePage(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text="Restore", bd=1)

class SideMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, pady=8)

        self.btn_backup = tk.Button(self, text="BACKUP", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(BackupPage))
        self.btn_restore = tk.Button(self, text="RESTORE", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(RestorePage))
        self.btn_progress = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRESS", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(ProgressPage))

        self.btn_backup.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill= tk.X, expand = True)
        self.btn_restore.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill= tk.X, expand = True)
        self.btn_progress.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill= tk.X, expand = True)

class ProgressPage(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text="Fortschritt", padx= 3)
        self.inner_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.inner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.inner_frame, bg="Yellow")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.inner_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set)

        self.hscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.inner_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscrollbar.set)

        self.canvas_inner_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="Red", bd=2)

        for i in range(1, 7+1):
            for j in range(1, 7+1):
                button = tk.Button(self.canvas_inner_frame, padx=7, pady=7, relief=tk.RIDGE,
                                text="[%d, %d]" % (i, j))
                button.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='news')

    
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.canvas_inner_frame, anchor=tk.NE)
        self.canvas_inner_frame.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas_inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))

    def update_canvas(self, event):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"), width=event.width, height= event.height)

app = Image()
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
Even after resizing the canvas correctly according to the first solution  it still breaks out of its parent:
[image]

If the canvas is not drawn, the buttons on the SideMenu are sized correctly. It seems to me that the canvas is completely ignoring the grid for some reason. Besides that it does not even draw the inner frame.

Comment: The `button_frame` should be resized automatically when new widget is added into it.

Comment: It does, but the canvas that holds the button_frame does not.

Comment: You don't need to resize the canvas, but need to update its `scrollregion` whenever the `button_frame` is resized.

Comment: What would be the best way to update the scrollregion? Thank you for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the canvas's scrollregion when the `button_frame` is resized.  Add the below code at the end of `MyApp.__init__()`:

```
buttons_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))
```

Comment: This still does not work. The canvas does not respect its boundaries and breaks out of its parent. Please take a look at the picture I provided above.

Comment: I edited the code, it doesnt seem to matter whether your solution is implemented or not. Now the canvas does not show its inner frame at all.